# cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable does not work while following all installation guide and reinstalling

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have followed the installation guide in [eloquent-sluggable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable).

This is my **Post** Model Structure :

```
namespace App;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableInterface;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model implements SluggableInterface
{
    use SluggableTrait;
    protected $sluggable = [
        'build_from' => 'post_title',
        'save_to'    => 'post_alias',
        'unique'     => true
    ];

    protected $guarded    = ['hits', 'comments_count', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'post_id';

    protected $dateFormat = 'U';

    public function post_pics ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PostPics');
    }

    public function categories ()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'category_post', 'post_id', 'cat_id');
    }

    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value){
        return $value;
    }
}
```

And added Appropriate entry to service Provider in **app.php** file :

```
yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::class,
Spatie\Glide\GlideServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableServiceProvider::class,
```

But when insert a new row to Post Table , **post_alias** field is null :

```
$newPost = new Post(['post_title'=>'How are you']);
$newPost->save();
```

What is problem and how can I solve that ?

**Update:**
I using **Laravel Framework version 5.1.23** (LTS). However when I use this Package in another Project base on However **version 5.1.19**, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many search and try trials and errors, first I remove package then I insert **"cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "dev-master"** exactly after **"laravel/framework": "5.1.*"**, and before other package in **composer.json** file.

after updating composer, it works fine. 
I do not know why this occurred.